# How can we use Postgresql advisory locks via Storm orm?

Tags: postgresql, storm-orm

We are using Storm orm for our postgresql database. Does anyone know how to use [advisory locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) via storm?

Comment: With most ORMs, the answer is "bypass the ORM and run SQL directly"

Comment: @Craig Ringer Thanks! I guess this is the only way to use advisory locks.